# Return an array through filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a filter

```
angular.module('filters', []).filter('check', function(data) 
{
  return function(name)
   {
     var a=new Array();
     a[0]="hello";
     a[1]="hi";
     return a;
   };
});
```

As you can see the filter is returning an array. How can i traverse through the content in the template (html page).

```
{{name|check:data}}
```

I am calling the filter and it returns the result as : `["hello","hi"]`

How can I traverse through the array in the template. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filters in ng-repeat.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnycpp/YbdXQ/7/

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="strInput" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="text in strInput|split">
            {{text}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


var angModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
angModule.filter('split',function() {
    return function(strData) {
        return strData.split(" ");
    }
});

angModule.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.strInput = "Provide your input here";
});
```